# How to load youtube video thumbnails in android?

Tags: android, video, youtube

How to make video thumbnails with youtube url in android?
at the time of clicking that thumbnail i want play that video in youtube application or web view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this: `ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail()` : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ThumbnailUtils.html#createVideoThumbnail(java.lang.String,%20int)

Comment: i don't think you can get the thumbnail from this method